# Get http.post in javascript then send a response

Tags: javascript, http, response

There's plenty of ways to do this in php, but I'm not a serverside, so is there a way to do this in pure JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

[See more](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS? Yes, but only on the server (the specifics would depend on which SSJS implementation you use, Express + NodeJS is popular at present).

You can't receive a POST request on the client. The client makes the request. The server makes the response. That is how HTTP works.